# Hibernate: Adding entity in many-to-many relationship causes unwanted update of the other entity

Tags: java, hibernate

Using Hibernate, given a many-to-many relationship between entities Payment and Refund and usgin optimistic locking with `@Version`

```
@Entity
class Payment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long paymentId;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Refund> refunds = new ArrayList<Refund>();

    @Version
    private long version;
}

@Entity
public class DRefund {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long refundId;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "refunds")
    private List<Payment> payments = new ArrayList<Payment>();

    @Version
    private long version;
}
```

If I load a `Payment` from database using Hibernate session add a `Refund` to it and then save the `Refund` using Hibernate session, the `Payment` row in db gets updated too:

```
insert into Refund (version, refundId) values (?, ?, ?)
update Payment set version=? where paymentId=? and version=?
insert into Payment_Refund (payments_paymentId, refunds_refundId) values (?, ?)
```

The `Payment` has not been changed in any way. Is this necessary or can the hibernate mappings be tweaked to avoid this behaviour? If I remove `@Version`, the `Payment` is not updated.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior can be configured using `@OptimisticLock` annotation:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@OptimisticLock(excluded = true)
private List<Refund> refunds = new ArrayList<Refund>();
```